# Trying to scroll a page: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked at other questions, with no success...

I'm just trying to keep the page scrolling slowly after load, follows the code:

CSS (Most of CSS is placed as embed files, this is just the styles applied to the content objects):

```
<style type="text/css">
.content {
    width: 98%;
    left: 1%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.block_1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 18.5%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    float: left;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 3px solid #999;
}
</style>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.slidebars({
      siteClose: true
    });
});

// Loading
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.loading').fadeOut(700);
    });
});
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#end').offset().top});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="loading">
  <div class="loading_msg">Carregando dados, aguarde...</div>
  <div class="loading_img"><img src="img/loader.gif" /></div>
</div>
<div class="sb-slidebar sb-left sb-width-custom" data-sb-width="300px"</div>
<div id="sb-site">
<div class="div_bg_header"><?php show_header_menu_dashboard($p_title); ?></div>
<div class="content" id="content">
  <div class="block_1"></div>
  <div class="block_1"></div>
  ...
  <a id="end"></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Grateful

Comment: You are calling it before the element is rendered to the page... Put the line inside the document ready

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I did it,the page still doesn't scroll, but the error is gone...

Comment: ohh..sorry didnt see your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.loading').fadeOut(700);
    });
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#end').offset().top});
});
```

in your CSS please set some height to the body,

```
body {
     height: 1500px;          
     }
```

and it will work well. current offset is just 16. so for visible scrolling 
please add the following style.

```
#end {
       margin-top: 500px;
       display: block;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it and the page still not scrolling, but the error is gone...

Comment: Now the page is scrolling, but only to the start of the element #content, parent of #end. anything I can do to scroll to the right place of the element?

Comment: @MarcosFelipe i didnt get it exactly.. you want to scroll to some specific Div??

Comment: Yes, I want it to scroll to the anchor #end, inside the div # content.

Comment: your code $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#end').offset().top}); will work. the offset value is just 16. that s the scroll top not visible. so please put the following styles it will work  #end {
                margin-top: 500px;
                display: block;
            }

Comment: My bad! I forgot to set the styles of the element #end.
Thank you so much for your help!